# jQuery .detach() not working when trying to change element position along the DOM with scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a div element with certain content move (Jump) between an specific area that has some duplicates inside an article while scrolling.

The div `#hotswapdiv` should be inserted inside each `<div id="div_identifier">
  </div>` while scrolling the page, by moving from the previous `#div_identifier` to the next `#div_identifier`.
It's like teleporting the `#hotswapdiv` between the elements with the same ID while scrolling.

JSFIDDLE:

https://jsfiddle.net/2n8k8g4L/7/

But for some reason it's not working.

Reference: https://api.jquery.com/detach/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you can only use one #div_identifier because it is an id , 
i think class="div_identifier" and .div_identifier will fix your issue

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kofijita/2n8k8g4L/10/ 
then the problem will be the scroll event don't have effect , you should insert the previous to the next according to the scroll